# How to remove Jquery Validation Error Messages on click of Clear Button

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, jqueryform

Edit User and Clear User are separate buttons.

Then how will Clear the error message on click of Clear Button using following statement
validator.resetForm(); ?

```
function clearUser(){ 
       // Need to clear previous errors here 
} 


function editUser(){     
    var validator = $("#editUserForm").validate({ 
            rules: {                             
                userName: "required" 
        },  
        errorElement: "span" ,                
        messages: { 
          userName: errorMessages.E2 
        } 
      }); 

     if(validator.form()){  
        // form submition code 

    } 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just make it global, eg:

```
var validator;
$(document).ready(function() {
       validator = $('#editUserForm');
});

function clearUser(){ 
       validator.resetForm();
} 

function editUser(){     
    validator.validate({ 
            rules: {                             
                userName: "required" 
        },  
        errorElement: "span" ,                
        messages: { 
          userName: errorMessages.E2 
        } 
      }); 

     if(validator.form()){  
        // form submition code 
    } 
}
```

then you need to eliminate the `var` in `editUser()`.

btw - you can also do:

```
function clearUser(){ 
       var validator = $('#editUserForm');
       validator.resetForm();
}
```

Comment: Not a perfect solution ...Should i repeat the same thing var validator = $('#editUserForm'); in Clear button ?

Comment: you can ... but you need not ... you can also use my first approach, which takes a global variable ...

Comment: maybe this plugin offers a list of validators, so you can pick your desired one to clear it. otherwise: i fear nope

Answer (score 7):

I tried the solution but i found there is a litle mistake in the previous solution, you should do this

When you validate your form, you get the validator like this

> var jqueryValidator =
>   jQuery("#myForm").validate();

and when you need to reset the form you just invoke the code like this

> jqueryValidator.resetForm();

Have a nice day =) I hope I can help you.